# Custom filter for list

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I'm trying to make a filter to only display elements on a list that matches with user input.

```
.filter('removeAcentos', function(){

    return function (source, item) {
    var re = new RegExp("" + item.toLowerCase() + "");
        angular.forEach(source, function(word){
            if(re.test(word.nomeCurso.toLowerCase()) === true){
                return true;
            }
        });
      //
        return false;
    };
})
```

And on the view:

```
<li ng-repeat="curso in ctrl.list| removeAcentos: ctrl.input ">
    ... <!-- display items from ctrl.list that match ctrl.input -->
</li>
```

However, I don't see why it isn't working. I tested the regex and the filter function returns true for the correct values. Any ideias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function doesn't return an array. The only thing the function returns is `false`

`forEach` really isn't the proper tool for the job either. Try using `Array.prototype.filter()` and remember to return the new array:

```
.filter('removeAcentos', function(){

    return function (source, item) {
       if(!source){
          return false;
       }  
        var re = new RegExp("" + item.toLowerCase() + "");
       // return filtered array
       return source.filter( function(word){
            return re.test(word.nomeCurso.toLowerCase());
        });

    };
})
```

Comment: Nice! But I'm using another filter function and I'd like to make it less cpu consuming as possible. Considering cpu consuming, is filter worth using over foraeach?

Comment: either way creates a loop, your forEach wasn't doing anything to create array to return